# Angular quiz game

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering if it is possible to hide the correct answers somehow in the front-end, using Angular or probably simple JS? So that no one can find the correct answer inspecting the source code.

Or the only way is to use a database, and if I use a database I need to use AJAX to get back to it and check the correct answer?

I don't have code, because it's only the theoretical part I'm interested now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything stored on the client side can be viewed in some way. Any enterprising person could find it some how. If you want to hide some data from anyone don't send it down to the client until absolutely necessary.

Sure there are ways to hide data without seeing it in source code directly but any caching or anything is exploitable in some way to find it. Simply looking at the network console section in chrome will allow you to see any data coming down from the server.

Comment: I understand. I was afraid of this answer :P Still I'm thinking about encode/decode... This might make some "pain" to the cheaters :P

Comment: Yea you can make it harder for people to get the data but at the end of the day even encoding it is not very hard to get by for anyone with experience or access to google. =]

Comment: Probably if I write my own encoding/decoding functions?

Comment: Yes but even if you do some kind of encryption on the data to send down it will need to either be decrypted once there to compare to users answer or encrypt the users answer to compare to your encrypted answer. Either way now the code for either encrypting or decrypting is on the client side so anyone can reverse engineer it. Your best bet is to handle this server side.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data using the [Angular Cache Factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory). This is a local-storage option that it appears you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would send the answer to the server and check it there. I think this is the only way to make it.

And 'YES' AJAX, RESTful Webservices or Websockets are needed to solve this problem.